# Reading char by char is best solution?

Tags: c#, text-files

So thing is I have to get some data from file and save it to database.

File have structure that at start there are some configuration lines, and then there is `"$START"` text which is beginning for my operations.

I was wandering how I can get all the information BEFORE this mark `("$START")`, and then proceed further.

I can't search line by line, because after `"$START"` declaration there is just one long for 16k chars line...

I didn't work with files for some time now, so my question is what will be best solution for it?

Comment: To me it is a bit unclear what's being asked; why would character-wise reading of the file be considered bad? On the other hand, would reading the entire file into memory be possible?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "one long for 16k chars line". (Would it really be a problem to read a 16k line anyway?) It would really help if you could show us an example of the file rather than just describing it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [string.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).

```
string data = "...your text data";
string[] splitted = data.Split(new string[] { "$START" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Then you have both sections of the data separated out and you can access them like this:

```
string configuration = splitted[0];
string data = splitted[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

What you consider best is the question, but this would certainly be easy to maintain and understandable. This sample uses regex:

```
string yourTextFileString = File.ReadAllBytes(@"filename.txt");

string textAfterStart = Regex.Replace(yourTextFileString, @"(.*)\$START(.*)", "$2", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: You're just removing the separator.

Comment: @Rawling: better now?

Comment: The first answer would've taken `xxx$STARYyyy` and returned `xxxyyy` instead of `yyy`. This one returns `yyy`, it just does it in a weird way ("find `xxx$STARTyyy` and replace it with `yyy` and tell me the result" rather than "find `xxx$STARYyyy` and tell me what `yyy` is")

Comment: You are right. It was my mistake. I usually use `Match` and there it would work.

Answer (score 0):

ok, if I get it right you have a file like this:

IMPORTANT_CODE_$START_UNINPORTANT_CODE

you can do

```
    String yourTextFile = File.ReadAllText("filename.txt");
    string importantText = yourTextFile.Substring(0, yourTextFile.IndexOf("$START"));
```

But if the file is to big you should do it like this:

```
    string operation = String.Empty;
    using (Stream s = new FileStream("filename.txt", FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        string text = String.Empty;
        while (s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            text += Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
            if (text.Contains("$START"))
            {
                operation = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf("$START"));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Your operation: {0}", operation);
```

Comment: That will cause a massive amount of string operations if the file is long.